# Regular Expressions: low-caps, dots, zero spaces

Tags: php, regex, whitespace, preg-match

how do I write an expression which checks for lowcaps, dots, and without any white space in the string?

the code below so far was trying to check for lowcaps and dots (it does not work anyway!) but I don't know how to add in the expression for white spaces.

```
# check for matches of lowcaps or lowcaps with a dot
if (!preg_match('/([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9\.])/', $cst_value))
{
  $error = true;
  echo ' please use lowcaps only with dot(s) and without any spacing.';
}
```

Comment: To the OP, and all the answers using `[a-z]`... "touché". All "lowercase", but won't match the proposed regexes. To the OP: should it?

Comment: Lowcaps = lowercase capitals? That’s like “tiny giants”.

Comment: You do not need to escape the `.` inside a character class. Your character class should be `[a-z0-9.]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[a-z0-9.]` matches a lower-case letter or a digit or a dot.
`[^a-z0-9.]` matches all characters that are not a lower-case letter or a digit or a dot.
So if `/[^a-z0-9.]/` matches anywhere the string contains something other than lc-letter,digit or dot. If it does not match your condition is fulfilled.

```
if ( !preg_match('/[^a-z0-9.]/', $cst_value) ) {
  // only lower-case letters, digits or dots
}
```

or without digits

```
if ( !preg_match('/[^a-z.]/', $cst_value) ) {
  // only lower-case letters or dots
}
```

---

update: example:

```
foreach( array('abcdef', 'abc de', 'abc.de', 'aBcde') as $cst_value) {
  echo $cst_value, ': ';
  if ( !preg_match('/[^a-z.]/', $cst_value) ) {
    echo " ok.\n";
  }
  else {
    echo "failure\n";
  }
}
```

prints

```
abcdef:  ok.
abc de: failure
abc.de:  ok.
aBcde: failure
```

Comment: You either have to remove the ^ from the character group or the ! in the expression.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Maybe the !, but certainly not the ^. Example added.

Comment: @Felix is right, you're coding in circles with that double negative.  I'd go with `/^[a-z0-9.]+$/` (good) or `/[^a-z0-9.]/` (bad).

Comment: @Alan: Ok, then remove the ! and switch the if/else branches if it really bothers you.

Comment: All of this works OK if you don't care about anything other that English alphabet characters. If you do, You should use \p{Ll} to match "lowercase characters". It also catches e.g. æøå from the Norwegian language :). More on Regex and Unicode here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 /^[a-z0-9.]+$)/
```

Should do it. Just think about that *only small letters, dots and digits are allowed*. The expression will not match if any white-space is included. Btw. you don't have to escape meta-characters in a capture group.

`^` and `$` indicates that the whole string should only contain those characters in the capture group (they mark the start and the end of the string) and the `+` says that at least one of these characters must occur. Depending on your needs you can change it to e.g. `{3,}` which means that the string must be at least 3 characters long.

Example:

```
$values=array("fooBar", "123.45", "foo bar", "foo.bar");

foreach($values as $value) {
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9.]+$/', $value))
    {
         echo "Not valid: $value\n";
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Not valid: fooBar
Not valid: foo bar
```

Comment: thanks. it works well but if I tested it with an URL with http:// at the beginning.

it will print this URL in the not match's output.

why is that? can I accept URL inputs?

thanks

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Well, as I said, the regular expressions basically means: Accept everything that is either small latter, a digit or a dot. But `http://` contains `:` and `/` too. You would have to add those characters to the character class too, but it won't validate whether the URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
if ( preg_match( '/[^a-z0-9.]/' ) ) {
    $error = true;
}
```

Keep in mind, I removed the !. Now if this matches, you get the error. VolkerK reversed it but forgot to remove the !, I think.

Also, http://regexpal.com/ is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

`'/^[a-z0-9.]+$/'` should be the right regex.