# Regular expression to only allow lower-case letters

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expressions: low-caps, dots, zero spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579531/regular-expressions-low-caps-dots-zero-spaces)

How could I change the regular expression below to only allow lower-case letters?

```
function valid_username($username, $minlength = 3, $maxlength = 30)
{

    $username = trim($username);

    if (empty($username))
    {
        return false; // it was empty
    }
    if (strlen($username) > $maxlength)
    {
        return false; // to long
    }
    if (strlen($username) < $minlength)
    {

        return false; //toshort
    }

    $result = ereg("^[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+$", $username); //only A-Z, a-z and 0-9 are allowed

    if ($result)
    {
        return true; // ok no invalid chars
    } else
    {
        return false; //invalid chars found
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Is it not as simple as `ereg("^[a-z0-9_\-]+$", $username);` ? But ereg function is deprecated as of PHP 5.3 http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php

Comment: With regular expressions, who knows?

Comment: regular expressions aren't magic. Why didn't you just test it?

Comment: jtheman : This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have both A-Z and a-z in your character class, just omit the A-Z to only allow for the a-z (lowercase) letters.  I.e.

```
"^[a-z0-9_\-]+$"
```

Answer (score 3):

You just remove the `A-Z` from the regular expression.

Also, since you are already using a regular expression you can just put everything into it, like this:

```
function valid_username($username, $minlength = 3, $maxlength = 30)
{
    $regex = "/^[a-z0-9_\-]{{$minlength},{$maxlength}}$/";

    return preg_match($regex, trim($username)) === 1;
}
```

It will make sure that the username is not empty, is of the permitted length, and that it only contains allowed characters.

Comment: This is not an answer to his question.

Comment: I think this not only answers his question, but greatly simplifies the function he was trying to write. All the better. (Plus, it helped me with my issue a lot.)

Answer (score 2):

The function `ereg` is deprecated. Use preg_match. Why don't you just use the function `strtolower`? preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $nickname);

EDIT:

> preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', $user);

Comment: Correct but that is not the answer to his question...

Answer (score 1):

The best option is a combination of Dave's and Jordi12100"s answer:

Use `pre_match()` and drop out the A-Z