# RegEx to make sure that the string contains at least one lower case letter in the given string

Tags: java

For example, if the given string is "HELLO world", the output should be **true** as the string has satisfied  at least one lowercase letter condition.

```
try {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\w*[a-z]\w*$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
    result = matcher.matches();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //print something
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to only allow lower-case letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107331/regular-expression-to-only-allow-lower-case-letters)

Comment: `Pattern.compile("[a-z]").matcher(password).find()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not the cleanest solution, but looping through the String like this would also get you the result you want. This function returns true when the string holds one not capital letter.

It doesn't use regex but it also gives you the option to check the String characters for other things you need to verify.

```
    private static boolean checkString(String str) {
        char ch;
        boolean lowerCaseFlag = false;
        for(int i=0;i < str.length();i++) {
            ch = str.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
                lowerCaseFlag = true;
            }
        }
        return lowerCaseFlag;
    }
```

Comment: What’s the point of setting `lowerCaseFlag = true;` and continuing the loop instead of doing `return true;` immediately? And why do you declare `ch` outside the loop?

Comment: I've let the function open the insert more checks, like a number etc..